# Mysql: Compare fields of 3 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id      name    dob
007     name1   19680514
007     name2   20110830
16842   name3   19660927
250718  name3   19660927
253692  name4   19350328
25576   name5   19520813
25576   name5   19520813
```

I need:
- a SELECT statement that gives me every row where the id is the same as in another row, but the correspoinding name or dob differ.
example output:

```
id  name    dob
007 name1   19680514
007 name2   20110830
```

- a second statement that gives me every row where the name and (!) dob are the same as in another row, but the id differs.
  example output:

  ```
  id     name   dob
  16842  name3  19660927
  250718 name3  19660927
  ```

Background:
Completely identical rows are allowed, but:
- every id should be unique for a combination of name&dob
- every combination of name&dob should have only one id assigned.

So I want to find out the entries with errors to be able to manually correct them.

Thank you!

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Strawberry formatted your question nicely for you, why did you go and ruin it?

Answer (score 0):

First query:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table yt
INNER JOIN (
SELECT
id
FROM
your_table
GROUP BY id 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) sq ON yt.id = sq.id
```

Second query:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table yt
INNER JOIN (
SELECT
name, dob
FROM
your_table
GROUP BY name, dob 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) sq ON yt.name = sq.name AND yt.dob = sq.dob
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT statement that gives every row where the id is the same as in another row, but the corresponding name or dob differ. example output:

```
select * from tbl t1
join tbl2 t2 
on t1.id = t2.id
where (t1.name <> t2.name) or (t1.dob <> t2.dob)
```

Statement that gives every row where the name and (!) dob are the same as in another row, but the id differs. example output:

```
select * from tbl t1
join tbl2 t2 
on t1.name = t2.name AND t1.dob = t2.dob
where (t1.id <> t2.id)
```